# interpreting the overall time in ping results

Tags: time, ping

I have two different machines I am doing pings on.

The hosts setup of the machine (OS, installed software, etc.) are identical. The only  difference is they are in two different networks.

These are the results:

Machine nr 1:

Machine nr 2:

The time for each echo is very low, however, the overall time is very different (22sec for machine nr 1, 4sec for machine nr 2).

I was wondering how I should interpret these results.

Is this because one network is slower than the other (in terms of download speed)?

Comment: Please post text as text,  and not as images  (screenshots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behaviour is likely different because beaglebone-03 is not identical to beaglebone-23.

It appears to have DNS configured.  See how the output is different, "64 bytes from ion...." vs "64 bytes from 15..."

Comment: amazing how incompetent I am